# Media player not playing mp3 files in android 2.3

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I want to play audio in my application.I am using android studio . I created a raw directory in res folder and place mp3 files there.Audio working perfectly on higher apis like I am testing on Lollipop emulator its works fine and not working on api 2.3+.
Here is my code

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
 mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.bismillah);
 mediaPlayer.start();
```

Whats wrong in this code .Need help ?

Comment: By "_not working on API 2.3+_" do you mean that it literally does nothing or that it gives an error? What does the log say?

Comment: Nothing no errors I have device contains 2.3.4

Comment: Check the [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html).

Comment: still nothing related to media player